# Unable to add node via OpsCenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

When trying to add a node via OpsCenter 5.0.1 I get the following

```
The Ec2Snitch is being used by this cluster. Provisioning nodes using this endpoint_snitch is not supported at this time.
```

Which seems contrary to the instructions given [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/online_help/opscAddingNode_t.html).

Comment: Could you provide some more context here such as some snippets of your opscenterd.log file? This might give some more information as to this error. You can also turn on opscenter log debugging following the instructions here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/configure/opscConfigLogging.html

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Which presents after using the AMI via this guide: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/install/installAMI.html.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, just add the new node using dsedelegate snitch, after the provisioning it's done, change the snitch to ec2snitch, and restart the node and thats it

Comment: when I change to dsedelegate snitch, the cluster can no longer connected, how do you solve that issue? thanks!